# WordPress Add [cdata] to title tag in rss feed

Tags: rss, feed

i have this feed http://www.jobseeker.gr/?feed=job_feed and i want to adding [CDATA] to title tag. I try to add this to functions.php but with no luck.

```
add_filter('the_title_rss', 'job_modify_post_title');
function job_modify_post_title ( $title ) {
    if ( is_feed('job_feed' ) ) { 
       return '<title><![CDATA[' . $title . ']]></title>';   
    }
}
```

Any help?

Best Regards,
Panagiotis Mitsinigkos

Comment: It seems a custom feed, how do you generate it?

Comment: It is generated by the wp job manager plugin. I don't use any custom template feed.

Comment: In that case, I think you should contact with plugin developer. I we don't know how the feed is coded, we can not know how to interact with it or why your code is not working. That is the reason that [questions about third party plugins are off-topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: According to the plugin author the job_feed code in WP Job Manager handles the query but not the output. The output is handled entirely by WordPress.

Comment: I see, let me investigate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`is_feed()` acept only one parameter to specify the feed type you want to check, like rss, atom, and so on. `job_feed` is not a valid feed type.

If you want to modify title of feed posts of some type, something like this should do the job:

I think this code should work:

```
add_filter( 'the_title_rss', 'job_modify_post_title' );
function job_modify_post_title ( $title ) {
    if ( 'your_post_type' === get_post_type() )
       $title = '<![CDATA[' . $title . ']]>';   

    return $title;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help it works great! Now i am going to try adding cdata to the title feed with wp-title-rss filter.