# Add ![CDATA] to permalink rss

Tags: rss, feed

in the next part of adding ![CDATA] to title tag as you can see by the link below

[WordPress Add [cdata] to title tag in rss feed](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/237635/wordpress-add-cdata-to-title-tag-in-rss-feed)

now i am trying to add ![CDATA] to the link tag using `the_permalink_rss`
This is the code i have so far:

```
//Add cdata to job permalink rss
add_filter( 'the_permalink_rss', 'add_cdata_to_permalink' );

function add_cdata_to_permalink ( $permalink) {
       $permalink = get_post_type_archive_link( get_query_var('job_listing') );
       return '<![CDATA[' . $permalink . ']]>';
```

And this is the output `<link>http://![CDATA[]]</link>`when it should be

`<link><![CDATA[permalink]]></link>`

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 2):

The problemn and its solution is very similar to the [other question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/237635/wordpress-add-cdata-to-title-tag-in-rss-feed). You are using [`get_post_type_archive_link()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type_archive_link/) incorrectly. That function accept only one parameter and it is the **post type identifier** for what you want to get the archive link, and I'm almost sure that `get_query_var('job_listing')` does not return a post type identifier.

For example, if the post type is `job_listing`, the use of `get_post_type_archive_link()` should be:

```
$permalink = get_post_type_archive_link( 'job_listing' );
```

Note that `get_post_type_archive_link()` returns `false` if the post type is registered with `'has_archive' => false` or, what it is your cse, if the post type identifier is not valid.

Also, take in account that the value returned by `the_permalink_rss` filter **is escaped using `esc_url()`**, as you can see in the [source code of `the_permalink_rss()` funciton](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_permalink_rss/#source),, so it is probably that you can not get the result you want because, I think, that function tries to escape a valid URL but a string starting with `<!CDATA` is not a valid URL. You can perform this simple test to see what I mean:

```
$test = '<![CDATA[ https://example.com/some-post ]]>';
// Outputs string(0) ""
var_dump( esc_url( $test ) );

$test = 'https://example.com/some-post';
string(29) "https://example.com/some-post"
var_dump( esc_url( $test ) );
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. The post type is registered with `'has_archive'    => $has_archive`

Comment: As for the `esc_url()` i don't know how to parse it to the function. I haven't do it before.

Comment: `esc_url()` is used by `the_permalink_rss()` function. Whatever value you return in the filter is passed to `esc_url()` before it is echoed by `the_permalink_rss()` function. I hope you understand what i mean.  See the reference I linked in the question. About `'has_archive' => $has_archive`, what is the value of `$has_archive`? If you don't know it, ask to the plugin developer, we can not know it (you are using WP Job Manager, right?).

Comment: i search and found this `$has_archive = _x( 'jobs', 'Post type archive slug - resave permalinks after changing this', 'wp-job-manager' );` i change the variable to  `$permalink = get_post_type_archive_link(  'jobs' );` but i get again in the output `<link>http://![CDATA[]]</link>`

Comment: Sorry but I have nothing new to say: **you must use the post type identifier**, are you sure it is `jobs`? if you are not sure what it is, ask to the plugin developer. Also, you should check the value returned by `get_post_type_archive_link()` before to check the output in the feed itself; when you are sure that `get_post_type_archive_link()` returns the correct value, then check the output. And, also again, is very probably that the `esc_url()` used by `the_permalink_rss()` will make imposible to do what you want (answer edited with a simple test).